# css vertical slider transition

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to create something similar to the animation below, but I can not understand where to start

[image: https://dribbble.com/shots/2985170-Healthy]

If you help me identify the type of animation or a web resource where you can document me and know more about it, I would appreciate it.

I started with the design:

```
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/braian125/r58tpjbg/2/)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using the slideChange event from Swiper, jQuery and animate.css

```
swiper.on('slideChange', function () {
  item = this.slides[this.activeIndex];
  itemInfo = $(item).find('.itemInfo');
  animation = 'rubberBand';
  itemInfo.addClass('animated ' + animation);        
  window.setTimeout( function(){
    itemInfo.removeClass('animated ' + animation);
  }, 1000);

  animation = 'jello';
  el = $(item).find('.itemPic');
  el.addClass('animated ' + animation);
  window.setTimeout( function(){
    el.removeClass('animated ' + animation);
  }, 1000);
});
```

[Animate CSS](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Answer (score -2):

Based on the image provided, feels something like animation library like [react-move](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-move) and [GreenSock](https://greensock.com/examples-showcases).

Please refer this [link](https://blog.logrocket.com/comparing-the-top-js-animation-libraries-for-use-in-react-apps-e3ba5ccad68d) for information.

There's a UI expert that I follow on twitter [Justin Marson](http://justinmarsan.com/) who does lot of animation work, you can can in touch with him for more research on this.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, I appreciate your help, it's very interesting.
remember that some time ago I worked on a project with animate.css https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/